# position a div at bottom of screen but dont allow content behind it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am trying to make chat app like layout with CSS. So for this I need a input text at the bottom of the screen. I put it with `position:fixed; bottom: 0;` and it is fixed at bottom so its good but the problem is when the messages above it are increasing they are going behind the input div and hiding there, last message even not showing when scroll.

Code is:

```
<div id='chat_window'>
    <ul id="messages" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></ul>
    <div class="panel-footer" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="my_msg" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="my_msg_submit">Send</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what is the best way to make the messages not go behind the input and only be above the input always for different screen heights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use position: fixed that element is taken out of the document flow and positioned relative to the browser window.  This means your other div is not aware of the fixed element at the bottom of the screen so you will have to compensate for the footer's height by adjusting the height of the content div to subtract out the height of the footer.

One way of doing this in newer browsers is by using the CSS [calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc) expression.
See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/agola/47ESP/) example code in action.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        html, body { 
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #main {
            overflow: auto;
            height: calc(100% - 30px);
        } 

        #footer {
            margin-left: 5px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            height: 30px;
        } 
    </style>

    <body>
        <div id='main'>
            <ul id="messages" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0;">
                <li>message 1</li>
                <li>message 2</li>
                <li>message 3</li>
                <li>message 4</li>
                <li>message 5</li>
                <li>message 6</li>
                <li>message 7</li>
                <li>message 8</li>
                <li>message 9</li>
                <li>message 10</li>
                <li>message 11</li>
                <li>message 12</li>
                <li>message 13</li>
                <li>message 14</li>
                <li>message 15</li>
                <li>message 16</li>
                <li>message 17</li>
                <li>message 18</li>
                <li>message 19</li>
                <li>message 20</li>
                <li>message 21</li>
                <li>message 22</li>
                <li>message 23</li>
                <li>message 24</li>
                <li>message 25</li>
                <li>message 26</li>
                <li>message 27</li>
                <li>message 28</li>
                <li>message 29</li>
                <li>message 30</li>
                <li>message 31</li>
                <li>message 32</li>
                <li>message 33</li>
                <li>message 34</li>
                <li>message 35</li>
                <li>message 36</li>
                <li>message 37</li>
                <li>message 38</li>
                <li>message 39</li>
                <li>message 40</li>
                <li>message 41</li>
                <li>message 42</li>
                <li>message 43</li>
                <li>message 44</li>
                <li>message 45</li>
                <li>message 46</li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="panel-footer" >
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="my_msg" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="my_msg_submit">Send</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: works nice like was hoping (tested on FF and Chrome).

Comment: @user2104070 glad it worked for you.  I updated the sample to removed the unnecessary #container div.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with pure CSS:

```
#chat_window {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

just put it on div container of chat window. not use position fixed.

Comment: post a jsfiddle with your html, and css

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a margin bottom to the list of messages, like so:

```
<ul id="messages" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0 0 30px 0; padding: 0;"></ul>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3nETE/1/

Comment: but I think this will not work when the input div is more than 30px (or 50px)?

Comment: You could specify a fixed height for the .panel-footer class but the input shouldn't be changing its height anyway. If it was a textarea that would be a different story but even then you can set a max-height on the div and make sure the margin is always more than the max-height.

Comment: but if on small screen size like mobile the height of .panel-footer will be different than desktop so we can't make a fixed height I think?

Comment: When you give a height to a div it will be that height regardless of the content or screen size. Content can get cutoff (or spill out, which is where the overflow: rule comes into play) but the height will not change. If the only content is the input and button then (most) mobile devices will display it fine. It would have to be a very very narrow screen to be cutoff.

Comment: Ok. With your jsfiddle when scroll up some content is still behind the input `.panel-footer`. Is there any way to not go behind the `.panel-footer` when scrolling up or down?

Comment: Yep, you can do similar to what Dan did in his bootply.
    .panel-footer {
        width:100%;
        background-color: (whatever color you want);
    }

That will prevent you from seeing the messages scroll behind it. http://jsfiddle.net/3nETE/2/